# Регистрация, выделение ресурсов в веб приложениях

Tags: веб-сервер, структуры, регистрация, хранение-данных, crm

Как организуется (какими средствами, методами) как структурируется регистрация нового аккаунта в таких веб приложениях как например облачная СРМ. Я хочу понять, что происходит после регистрации нового пользователя:

1. Как происходит создание экземпляра приложения (или может там вообще другой процесс
2. Как организуется хранение пользовательских данных (создается отдельная БД или данные хранятся скопом и имеют реляции по ID)

Или например такие веб сервисы как Конструкторы сайтов. Как там организуется хранение пользовательских данных, привязка домена, маршрутизация?

Понимаю что тема очень обширная, буду признателен как за ссылки ( в том числе на english публикации ) так и на любые ответы! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не стоит просить ответы-ссылки - они запрещены правилами :) По теме - это называется multi-tenancy, есть куча вариантов реализации, в зависимости от требуемой изоляции данных и поддержки со стороны вашей платформы - от колонки tenantid во всех таблицах в базе до полностью отдельных экземпляров приложения.

Comment: Все перечисленные вами способы применяются на практике. И избегайте задавания нескольких вопросов в одном. Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, чтобы в нём остался **один** вопрос.